# .NET - Order list by internal lists SUM

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Having some trouble getting this right, I have a list of transaction that I have grouped by account in LINQ, that now gives me an enumerable of all the accounts, each with an enumerable of their transactions within. I now want to take that list, and order it by the sum of the transactions of each group, but it doesn't seem to be working, this is what I have so far:

```
var memberTrans = trans.GroupBy(o => o.ShareAccountId);
var transOrdered = memberTrans.OrderByDescending(o => o.Sum(i => i.TransactionAmount));
```

The idea being, I can do .First() and get the account that has had the highest net increase during the period, and .Last() to get the account with the lowest net increase.

Assuming I have data as follows (Simplified)

- Account 1 : 300
- Account 1 : -300
- Account 2 : 100
- Account 3 : 50
- Account 2 : -20

So the first grouping gives me:

Account 1:

- Tran: 300
- Tran:-300

Account 2:

- Tran: 100
- Tran:-20

Account 3:

- Tran:50

Now I'd like to order it by the SUM of the transactions within each group, so we have the list:

Account 2:

- Tran: 100
- Tran:-20

Account 3:

- Tran:50

Account 1:

- Tran: 300
- Tran:-300

Hopefully that's clear enough, any help greatly appreciated!

Edit: More code for clarity:

`var tranOrder = trans.GroupBy(o => o.ShareAccountId).OrderByDescending(g => g.Sum(t => t.TransactionAmount));`

```
        var bigUp = tranOrder.First().First();
        var bigDown = tranOrder.Last().First(); 
        report.BiggestMovementUp = tranOrder.First().Sum(o => o.TransactionAmount);
        report.BiggestMoverUp =
            (bigUp.Member.Title + " " + bigUp.Member.Forename + " " + bigUp.Member.Surname + " - ID " + bigUp.Member.MemberID).Trim();
        report.BiggestMovementDown = tranOrder.Last().Sum(o => o.TransactionAmount);
        report.BiggestMoverDown =
          (bigDown.Member.Title + " " + bigDown.Member.Forename + " " + bigDown.Member.Surname + " - ID " + bigDown.Member.MemberID).Trim();
```

Comment: Remember to wrap your code in the code format so that it's easier to read.

Comment: Errors? Exceptions? Your expectation on the result does not correlate with actual result? What exactly is wrong?

Comment: Your LINQ looks pretty spot on to me... What do you get when you try it?

Comment: No exceptions, the list simply does not get put into any order, it remains in it's original order

Comment: @Daniel Are you still using the original list, rather than using the value of `transOrdered`? LINQ `OrderBy` doesn't order the original, it creates an ordered "view" of the original.

Comment: Have you debugged the result of each `o.Sum(i => i.TransactionAmount)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  var v = (from acc in accs
           group acc by acc.ShareAccountId into g
           orderby g.Sum(x => x.TransactionAmount) descending
           select g.Sum(x => x.TransactionAmount));
```

That should do it, you can do whatever you want in the select. I tested this too.

Comment: This seems to do the trick! I am so used to writing the other way of doing it, thanks!

Comment: @DanielDawes Depends what your used too, this is good for those who are more SQL driven then .NET as you can interpret it like that - the other way is more if you like lambdas and .NET in my opinion.

Comment: Other than the last `Select`, this is identical to @DanielDawes's original code. I wonder why this works when his doesn't.

Comment: @Rawling it is indeed. I think the select could actually be the difference, because you are trying to order by something your not outputting - I replicated his issue (I was getting 300 and 300 as amounts instead of 400 and 300 for example) once I selected the output that I was ordering it worked.

Comment: @LukeHennerley I just posted an answer more specific to the method chaining in case you were curious

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
internal class Program
    {
        private class AccountOperation
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public int Amount { get; set; }
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<AccountOperation> ops = new List<AccountOperation>
            {
                new AccountOperation { Id = 1, Amount = 300},
                new AccountOperation { Id = 1, Amount = -300},
                new AccountOperation { Id = 2, Amount = 100},
                new AccountOperation { Id = 3, Amount = 50},
                new AccountOperation { Id = 2, Amount = -20},
            };

            foreach (var operationsByAccount in ops
                .OrderByDescending(z => z.Amount)  // Orders all amounts descending
                .GroupBy(z => z.Id) // Groups by account ID
                .OrderByDescending(z => z.Sum(z2 => z2.Amount))) // Orders groups of operations per accounts descending (by sum of amounts)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Operation " + operationsByAccount.Key);
                foreach (var operation in operationsByAccount)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\tAmout " + operation.Amount);
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Outputs:

- Operation 2

  - Amout 100
  - Amout -20
- Operation 3

  - Amout 50
- Operation 1

  - Amout 300
  - Amout -300

Answer (score 0):

For the fix to your method chaining version:

```
var v = accs.GroupBy(acc => acc.ShareAccountId)
        .OrderByDescending(g => g.Sum(x => x.TransactionAmount))
        .Select( g => g.Sum(x => x.TransactionAmount));
```

Admittedly, I let Resharper do this for me from the LINQ syntax :)